# converting from max to min in an optimization function?

Tags: optimization

I have the following maximization objective function related to a svm
\begin{align}
\max_{\gamma,\omega,b} & \  \frac{\hat{\gamma}}{\|\omega\|}\\
\mbox{s.t. } & \ \ \ y^{(i)}(\omega^{T}x^{(i)} + b) \geq \hat{\gamma}, \ \ i = 1, \ldots m
\end{align}

Then the author says that: 
$\mbox{maximizing } \hat{\gamma}/ \|\omega\| = 1/\|\omega\| $

is the same as minimizing: $\|\omega\|^2$, why is this?

and that our final optimization function is:
\begin{align}
\max_{\gamma,\omega,b} & \  \frac{1}{2}\|\omega\|^2\\
\mbox{s.t. } & \ \ \ y^{(i)}(\omega^{T}x^{(i)} + b) \geq 1, \ \ i = 1, \ldots m
\end{align}

For what I see he considers that $\gamma=1$, but if I replace directly I will end up with: $\max 1/\|\omega\|$, but from where the author raises $\|\omega\|$ to the power of $2$ and divided by $2$. Is he integrating $\|\omega\|$?

Any help?

Comment: Purely Math question to me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. there are other questions related to math here, so I dont see what is the deal

Answer (score 1):

OK, you want to maximize a function of the form
$$
   f(x) = 1/g(x)
$$
where both $f(x)>0$  and $g(x) > 0$.  Well think about the grapg of the function $f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$.  This is a decreasing function, you can se it directly from the graph (draw it!) or by calculating the derivative $f'(x)=-1/x^2$.  So, you want $f(x) $ large? then, since it is **decreasing** in $x$, you want $x$ small, that is, you want to minimize $x$. You can do the generalization yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What the author means that you solution is defined up to a multiplier. If a triple $(\gamma,w,b)$ is a solution then for $k>0$, $(k\gamma,kw,kb)$  is also a solution. So assuming that $\gamma>0$  we just can assume that $\gamma=1$. 
The power 2 appears only to have the problem more analytical. Sum of squares ($||w||^2$) is better than square root sum of squares. I does not affect on solution, since $\min ||w||$ is equivalent $\min ||w||^2$.

Comment: thanks, but from where the term 1/2 appears?

Comment: Why does it bother you? It just a multiplier  which does not affect a solution. But the derivative of $x^2/2$ is  just $x$ rather $2x$ for $x^2$.